# Xcode 8: Unable to Accept License Agreement on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Tags: macos, xcode

I have downloaded Xcode 8 from App Store. on clicking Xcode icon it is showing the following:

[image]

After clicking on Agree button it asks for the username and password. On entering the username and password nothing is happening.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your Mac? I assume XCode uses several helper processes, which might crash without error. (And I often experienced XCode problems to disappear after rebooting.)

Comment: @codingFriend1 Yes, i have tried it but no luck so far.

Answer (score 4):

Try using xcodebuild to accept the license. Quit Xcode and run the following:

```
sudo xcodebuild -license accept
```

You may need to use `xcode-select --switch` first to switch Xcode version if you have multiple Xcode apps on your system.

Comment: I have tried above command and got this  --> User-MAC:~ Himz$ sudo xcodebuild -license accept
Password:
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libwep
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x101DEF000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep
 /usr/local/lib/libwep: mmap() error 1 at address=0x101E02000, size=0x00008000 segment=__TEXT in Segment::map() mapping /usr/local/lib/libwep
User-MAC:~ Himz$

Comment: Awesome!  This helped me; Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 3):

The problem i was facing "Xcode 8 : Unable to Accept License Agreement on OS X El Capitan 10.11.6" is resolved.

**Cause :** It was blocked due to **Symantec and Web Sense installed in my macbook**

**Resolution :** Start your MacBook in **Safe Mode** (in safe mode there is no Symantec and web sense installed) and then install Xcode 8.

To start MacBook in safe mode try this: [OS X El Capitan: Start up in safe mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21875?locale=en_US)

Comment: after trying everything rebooting in safe mode solved my problem

Comment: Thanks this worked. I just turned off the Norton security.